# Copy a function to another position in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

```
for x = 1:30
   for y = 1:30
      A(x,y) = sin(2x + y);
   end end
```

---

```
for x = 1:30
   B(x) = sum(23 .* A (x, :));
end
```

I have function A and B. In the figure below, 
there are four blocks where the middle two blocks are function B.
After that, I need to duplicate the upper half of function B ( x = 1:15)
to the first block and the lower half of function B (x = 16:30)
to the fourth block. What is the approach to this solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is easy by concatenation of the parts:

```
C = [B(1:15) B B(16:30)]
```